# Hide row of data in matrix by field value

Tags: sql-server

I need to know how to code this. I am working with program numbers and there is one that I do not want to be displayed. I am trying:

```
=Fields!NoProg.Value="08007"
```

But then I do not know how to tell it:

```
(pseudocode)
if NoProg = 08007, then do not display.
```

Comment: You mean you're using that expression for the `Hidden` property and it does not do anything? I'm also just *assuming* you're referring to SSRS here.

Comment: No, I wish to write the correct code. I tried to put what I want to do in english. This is in the report environment of SQL Server. But yes, I wish it not display the data for that particular program number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see it, you have two options:

1. Filter out the row you don't want in your resulting dataset at the database side. This has the advantage of using indexes if you have them set up. This involves putting a `WHERE` clause into your query. If you cannot change the query or need the row to be in the resulting dataset but simply hidden, choose this option.

   ```
   SELECT ...
   FROM ...
   WHERE NoProg <> '08007'
   ```
2. Hide the row in the report, as you are already doing. This has the advantage of keeping the data in the resulting dataset but hiding it from that section of the report. If you are performing aggregation and need to include the row elsewhere but just hide the detail from view, choose this option. Keep in mind, this will not use any database indexes, so it requires one comparison for every row in the resulting dataset.

   ```
   <Hidden>=Fields!NoProg.Value="08007"</Hidden>
   ```